# json nested structure in angular 6

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am new to angular. I have requirement to send the data to backend system. The structure of the objects are like this

```
interface semester {
  Id: number;
  Semester: string;
  Year: number;
  course: course[];
}

interface course {
  CourseNumber: number;
  CourseTitle: string;
  CurriculumID: string;
}
```

My user interface will add a course each time on pressing add button and trying to develop a object as below and send it to backend api.

adding first course:

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":"20193",
      "Semester":"Fall",
      "Year":"2018",
      "course":[  
         {  
            "CourseNumber":"100",
            "CourseTitle":"CEU: Contemporary Collective Bargaining",
            "CurriculumID":"00004285"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and when add one more course in different semester

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":"20193",
      "Semester":"Fall",
      "Year":"2018",
      "course":[  
         {  
            "CourseNumber":"100",
            "CourseTitle":"CEU: Contemporary Collective Bargaining",
            "CurriculumID":"00004285"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Id":"20195",
      "Semester":"Spring",
      "Year":"2019",
      "course":[  
         {  
            "CourseNumber":"230",
            "CourseTitle":"American Indians of Minnesota",
            "CurriculumID":"00007541"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and third time when add a course o previous semester then strcture should be like as below

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":"20193",
      "Semester":"Fall",
      "Year":"2018",
      "course":[  
         {  
            "CourseNumber":"100",
            "CourseTitle":"CEU: Contemporary Collective Bargaining",
            "CurriculumID":"00004285"
         },
         {  
            "CourseNumber":"101",
            "CourseTitle":"Design Foundations",
            "CurriculumID":"00000897"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Id":"20195",
      "Semester":"Spring",
      "Year":"2019",
      "course":[  
         {  
            "CourseNumber":"230",
            "CourseTitle":"American Indians of Minnesota",
            "CurriculumID":"00007541"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Results captured from the form after button click

```
this.selectedSemester={Id: "20193", Semester: "Fall ", Year: "2018"};
this.selectedCourse={CourseNumber:"240",CourseTitle:"Painting",CurriculumID:"00001025"}
```

And wrote a addCourse method to capture the data in required format

```
courseList: semester[];
addCourse(){
  this.courseList.push({
  Id: this.selectedSemester.Id,
  Semester: this.selectedSemester.Semester,
  Year: this.selectedSemester.Year,
  course: this.selectedCourse
        }
      );
    }
```

Here in semester, Id is the unique key Id. Can anyone help one with syntax to form this object.

Comment: You mean you need an object that wraps semesters and courses together?

Comment: It would be meaningful if you can share what you have tried instead of just posting the requirement you wanted.You can form a **newCourse{ }** on click of _add_ button and then push that to **course[ ]** of the object with _id = semesterId_ to which you want to add the course.

Comment: Yes you are correct I am trying to push data in addCourse() function. I updated the question(Please check). When I trying to push the course its giving me error because I am pushing an single object instead of an array. So could you please help me  change the structure or any other place.

Comment: @DiabolicWords Yes I need to wrap smester and course together. I updated my question please check

Comment: I added a second answer considering your new information. Please, have a look at it. If this helped you, please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could handle the object according to your updated information:

```
courseList: Array<ISemester> = [];

addCourse(){
    this.selectedSemester={Id: "20193", Semester: "Fall ", Year: "2018", course: []};
    this.selectedCourse={CourseNumber:"240",CourseTitle:"Painting",CurriculumID:"00001025"}

    // Add the semester and get the reference to it
    const currentSemester = this.addSemester(this.selectedSemester);

    // Add the selected course to the referenced semester in the courseList
    this._addCourse(this.selectedCourse, currentSemester);
}

/**
 * This method first checks whether the semester is already listed.
 * If not, the semester will be added.
 * The method finally returns the reference to the semester object in the list.
 */
private addSemester(semester: ISemester): ISemester {
    let isInList: boolean = false;
    let currentSemester: ISemester;

    // walk through the semester list
    this.courseList.forEach(element => {
        // if the semester is already listed
        if(element.Id === semester.Id){
            // memorize this and let the return value (currentSemester) 
            // be a reference to the semester element in the list
            isInList = true;
            currentSemester = element;

            // stop iteration
            break;
        }
    });

    // if there was no match, add the semester to the courseList
    if(!isInList) {
       currentSemester = semester;
       this.courseList.push(semester);
    }

    return currentSemester;
}

private _addCourse(course: ICourse, semester: ISemester) {
    // if the course is not yet listed
    if(this.semester.course.filter(element => element.Id === course.Id).length < 0){
        // add it
        this.semester.course.push(course);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @DiabolicWords. I tried with the your approach I was able to push for addSemester but I am getting error at _addCourse function like as below

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'course' of undefined
    at PlanningComponent.push../src/app/AcademicPlanning/student/planning/planning.component.ts.PlanningComponent._addCourse (planning.component.ts:69)
    at PlanningComponent.push../src/app/AcademicPlanning/student/planning/planning.component.ts.PlanningComponent.addCourse (planning.component.ts:62)`

Please let me Know I need to share more info

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I corrected the code. Please note that `this.selectedSemester` now contains the field `course: []`. This should do it. Please, try again.

Comment: Thanks @DiabolicWords. So when I added course: [], the `_addCourse` function not adding any courses for the first time add because `semester.course.filter(element => element.CurriculumID === course.CurriculumID).length` is 0. so I changed `semester.course.filter(element => element.CurriculumID === course.CurriculumID).length>-1` then I could able to push the course into it.

Comment: And only thing missing here is, when I am adding a course, I should check the each semester object whether it is exist in it or not.

Answer (score 3):

You could assemble your objects this way

You have your interfaces

```
export interface ISemester {
    Id: number;
    Semester: string;
    Year: number;
    course: ICourse[];
}

export interface ICourse {
    CourseNumber: number;
    CourseTitle: string;
    CurriculumID: string;
}
```

You have models that implement the interfaces

```
export class Semester implements ISemester {
    Id: number;
    Semester: string;
    Year: number;
    course: ICourse[];
}

export class Course implements ICourse {
    CourseNumber: number;
    CourseTitle: string;
    CurriculumID: string;
}
```

You have a List of type ISemester where you push in semester-objects. This semester objects get course-objects which you push into their course-list.

```
const semesters: Array<ISemester> = [];

const semester1 = new Semester();
semester1.Id = 1000;
semester1.Semester = 'Semester1';
semester1.Year = 2018;

const course1 = new Course();
course1.CourseNumber = 1;
course1.CourseTitle = 'Title1';
course1.CurriculumID = '00123';

semester1.course.push(course1);

const course2 = new Course();
course1.CourseNumber = 5;
course1.CourseTitle = 'Title2';
course1.CurriculumID = '00124';

semester1.course.push(course2);

semesters.push(semester1);

const semester2 = new Semester();
semester1.Id = 1001;
semester1.Semester = 'Semester2';
semester1.Year = 2019;

const course3 = new Course();
course1.CourseNumber = 101;
course1.CourseTitle = 'Title4';
course1.CurriculumID = '00800';

semester1.course.push(course3);

semesters.push(semester2);
```

This results in a list of semesters that contain either one or n courses.